# Using two different dataset file formats to train model

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision

I am looking to train a model on computer vision for imsge prediction but I have an images dataset and a .csv dataset.

**Note**: both datasets have 6 classes A, B, C, D, E, F, only different is the file format.

Is it possible to train a model using both datasets to be able such that when a user uploads an image and passes it through the model for scanning predict image based on the class it is most similar to?